# iOS / Android Push Notification Categories / Sub Types / Taxonomy

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-push-notification

Many companies define different sub-types of push notifications. The users can opt-in/out of different sub-types based on their interests. See attached image from instagram where in settings you can choose to subscribe to different push notification sub types. The question: is there a way to specify the push notification sub-type in the payload of the notification and the ios / android os based on the user's choices, will it to them. In other words, can the server side just send any push notification with the sub-type field set and the os/paltform does the needful. Or should the server side handle this business logic and only send the relevant notification that people have subscribed ?

[image]

Comment: Typo: "will it to them"  --> "will show it to them"

Answer (score 2):

Server side should handle it. The only way to handle it on the device would be to push a silent notification, then when it wakes the app up (this is not consistent btw), you would check the key/values of the notification against the preferences of the user.

Its much better to have the server attribute which user has which notification 'categories' enabled and only send to the interested user.

Most push services (Amazon's SNS, Firebase) have groupings for you, so if you don't want to build that functionality yourself you have very cheap and easy options to achieve these things.

Comment: Thanks.  So by "grouping" in SNS do you mean topics ? Also, this means you will need maintain a DB of users and their preferences in the backend -- right ?

Comment: Yes to the topics, I honestly can't remember what verbiage they use.

Comment: The only things, when using Amazons SNS, you NEED is the association of your User object with the SNS-token you get when subscribing a APNS-token. 
And your backend sends a REST call to SNS, and you can either send to that individual user OR send to a topic.